# Add a linked select box to sign up form

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a sign up form and I want to add 2 linked select box to the form, the linked select box code works find separatly but when I try to add it into the form it doesn't show up.
I tried to add the code into a div under the password `block` but didn't work for me

EDIT: so we figured out that the problem isn't with the code but is something that i'm doing wrong with the Angular. when I open the project (in visual studio code) that includes the html,TS,CSS the select box won't show up. when we tried to run it not as an angular project and without the TS the select box did show up. can someone help me?

This is the linked select box:

```
<script>
var sel1 = document.querySelector('#sel1');
var sel2 = document.querySelector('#sel2');
var options2 = sel2.querySelectorAll('option');

function giveSelection(selValue) {
  sel2.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < options2.length; i++) {
    if(options2[i].dataset.option === selValue) {
      sel2.appendChild(options2[i]);
    }
  }
}

giveSelection(sel1.value);
</script>

<select id="sel1" onchange="giveSelection(this.value)">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2">
  <option data-option="a">apple</option>
  <option data-option="a">airplane</option>
  <option data-option="b">banana</option>
  <option data-option="b">book</option>
</select>
```

And this is the main sign up form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s10 offset-s1" id="panel">
            <div class="progress" *ngIf="showSpinner">
                <div class="indeterminate"></div>
            </div>
            <h3 id="title">Sign Up</h3>
            <div id="errorMsg" *ngIf="errorMessage">
                <span>{{errorMessage}}</span>
            </div>
            <form class="col s12" [formGroup]="signupForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="signupUser()">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="user_name" type="text" formControlName="username" autocomplete="off">
                        <label for="user_name">Username</label>
                        <span class="error" *ngIf="!signupForm.controls['username'].valid && signupForm.controls['username'].touched">
                            Username is required
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="email" type="email" formControlName="email" autocomplete="off">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <span class="error" *ngIf="!signupForm.controls['email'].valid && signupForm.controls['email'].touched">
                            Email is required
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="pass-word" type="password" formControlName="password">
                        <label for="pass-word">Password</label>
                        <span class="error" *ngIf="!signupForm.controls['password'].valid && signupForm.controls['password'].touched">
                            Password is required
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>







                <button class="btn waves-effect" id="signupbtn" [disabled]="!signupForm.valid">
                    Sign Up
                </button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope to get some help with that

Answer (score 0):

I added your linked select boxes to the form under password.  It works fine.  What specific problem or error message age you getting?

Update: added your css.  It's not causing the problem.  Try disabling your TS  file and see if the code works

```js
var sel1 = document.querySelector('#sel1');
var sel2 = document.querySelector('#sel2');
var options2 = sel2.querySelectorAll('option');

function giveSelection(selValue) {
  sel2.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < options2.length; i++) {
    if(options2[i].dataset.option === selValue) {
      sel2.appendChild(options2[i]);
    }
  }
}

giveSelection(sel1.value);
```

```css
#panel {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#signupbtn {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #64b5f6;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#title {
  background-color: #64b5f6;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
 
.error {
  color: red;
}
 
.indeterminate {
  background-color: #64b5f6 !important;
}
 
.input-field {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
 
#errorMsg {
  background: #f6b2b5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
 
#errorMsg span {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s10 offset-s1" id="panel">
            <div class="progress" *ngIf="showSpinner">
                <div class="indeterminate"></div>
            </div>
            <h3 id="title">Sign Up</h3>
            <div id="errorMsg" *ngIf="errorMessage">
                <span>{{errorMessage}}</span>
            </div>
            <form class="col s12" [formGroup]="signupForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="signupUser()">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="user_name" type="text" formControlName="username" autocomplete="off">
                        <label for="user_name">Username</label>
                        <span class="error" *ngIf="!signupForm.controls['username'].valid && signupForm.controls['username'].touched">
                            Username is required
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="email" type="email" formControlName="email" autocomplete="off">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <span class="error" *ngIf="!signupForm.controls['email'].valid && signupForm.controls['email'].touched">
                            Email is required
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="pass-word" type="password" formControlName="password">
                        <label for="pass-word">Password</label>
                        <span class="error" *ngIf="!signupForm.controls['password'].valid && signupForm.controls['password'].touched">
                            Password is required
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select id="sel1" onchange="giveSelection(this.value)">
                       <option value="a">a</option>
                       <option value="b">b</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="sel2">
                       <option data-option="a">apple</option>
                       <option data-option="a">airplane</option>
                       <option data-option="b">banana</option>
                       <option data-option="b">book</option>
                    </select>
                </div>







                <button class="btn waves-effect" id="signupbtn" [disabled]="!signupForm.valid">
                    Sign Up
                </button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I compile it (ng serve) the select box doesn't show up. https://imgur.com/lujuJEc  there is also a ts and css for this file, do you think the problem could be there?

Comment: what is a ts file? do you mean js for javascript? can you post a link to your site?

Comment: a type script file, i am still working on it so it's not possible to enter it. do you want i link the ts file?

Comment: why not first disable the ts and css files and see if the code works.  In the mean time go ahead and add the css and ts to your problem description

Comment: https://pastebin.com/76Rff2EJ will try to run just the html but the html file is based on the css and won't run like that if im correct

Comment: no, the html will run without your css it just won't look the same.  Your css is not causing the problem.  I'm not familiar with angular but try running without your ts file

Comment: doesn't work since it doesn't find the sign up components that exist in the ts file :/

Comment: can you post your code to https://codesandbox.io/s/angular  ??

Comment: well taking the code you posted without the html or css it works good. but for some reason when I try to run on my visual studio code (just the html) it won't load and returns errors.

Comment: I can't tell for sure but suspect the problem is in your ts file.  Can you try to strip it down to bare minimum?

Comment: i still don't understand how it works here for you without the TS file, but whenever i delete the TS file and try running the project it returns errors ...

Comment: well here we are not running angular.  You can either post your code to the sandbox so I can see what's going on or you can give me the url of your site.  Without one of those I can't help you

Comment: your code seems to be working in sandbox although you need to add your custom js. Do you know how to add js in the sandbox?

Comment: nope, also what do you mean by js? the java script code I sent in the begining?

Comment: as far as I can tell your problem is with angular.  I haven't used that before and at this point can't help you.

Comment: Thanks buddy you helped a lot, I hope someone will be able to help further with the angular (im also new to this)